# Springboot RestCall with injection dependancy

Tags: rest, spring-boot

I am having a project with following strucure with spring boot, when i am running the project and trying to access the url http://localhost:8080/sample/details it is not working, but when i remove all the annotation except @SpringBootApplicaiton, then the same works fine for the url. can anyone hint, where i am doing the mistake?

```
com.sample.controller
    --Main class (with annotated as @SpringBootApplication)
    --ControllerClass (which takes the @RequestMapping values)
com.sample.vo
    --POJO Class
com.sample.service
    --Interface class
com.sample.serviceImpl
    --Service implementation class
```

Main SpringBootClass class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan({
                "com.sample.service",
                "com.sample.serviceImpl"
               })
public class ServletContainer {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {
        ConfigurableApplicationContext applicationContext = new SpringApplicationBuilder(ServletContainer.class)
                .properties("spring.config.name:application",                       "spring.config.location:classpath:/propertyFileLication/").build().run(args);
    }
}
```

Controller Class:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/sample")
public class SampleController {

    @Autowired
    private SampleVO SampleVO;

    @Autowired
    private SampleService SampleService;

    @RequestMapping(value="/details",produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public List<SampleVO> prodDetails(){
        SampleVO SampleVO = new SampleVO();
        SampleService SampleService = new SampleServiceImpl();
        List<SampleVO> list = SampleService.fetchProductDetails(SampleVO);
        return list;
    }
}
```

POJO Class:

```
@Service
public class sampleVO {
    //something
}
```

Service Interface Class:

```
@Service
public interface SampleService {
    public List<SampleVO> fetchProductDetails(SampleVO SampleVO);
}
```

Service Implementation Class:

```
@Service
public class SampleServiceImpl implements SampleService{

    //Something

}
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: add your controller class package in componentscan

Comment: When i add controller package to component scan, then i tgives me error message while building the spring boot project as Field SampleVO in com.sample.controller.SampleController required a bean of type 'com.sample.vo.SampleVO' that could not be found. here i tried adding VO class package also in component scan, but same error persist.

Answer (score 0):

After changing the project structure slightly it got worked.

How i changed to is

```
com.sample.initializer
     --Main class (with annotated as @SpringBootApplication)
com.sample.controller
    --ControllerClass (which takes the @RequestMapping values)
com.sample.vo
    --POJO Class
com.sample.service
    --Interface class
com.sample.serviceImpl
    --Service implementation class


@ComponentScan({
                "com.sample.controller",
                "com.sample.vo",
                "com.sample.service",
                "com.sample.serviceImpl"
               })
```

Can someone tell me, do we need to handle controller and Spring-boot initializer class in separate package.